# Need to generate next date from a given date after certain given interval in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to generate a date from a given date after every 2 years and after every 6 months.

For example :

(For 2 Years)

Given_Date : 1-Jan-2016
Next_date  : 1-Jan-2020

// Since the 1-Jan-2018 has already passed.

(For 6 month)

Given Date : 1-dec-2017
Next Date : 1-June-2019

//  6 month interval based on start date.

So i tried to Use Edate and IF and Mod function.

EDATE(E3,IF(MOD(ROUND(DATEDIF(E3,TODAY(),"y"),0),2)=0,2,3)*12)

It kinda work only for next date but not for next to next date.  I need something dynamic that works for all the future dates.

Comment: So, if a `Given Date` **plus two years** has passed, you want to take the `Given Date`, add two years, then add 6 months?  If that `Given Date` + 2 yrs has *not* passed, just do `given date` + 2 years + 2 years?

Comment: Can you please provide us with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Try to have a read on `date()` function.. ||  I think `=date(year(A1)+2,month(A1),day(A1))` will do for the two years case. || Share with us how far you get for the 6 months case...

Comment: @BruceWayne Actually those 2 are seperate questions. First, given date and the two years has passed, it should add 2 more years to the later date and give the answer. For example Given date: 2016-01-01 so the later date is 2018-01-01 and since the laste date has passes it should give now 2020-01-01. 6 Month question is seperate but the logic i want is same.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yes your code works but for once only. for example the given date is 2016-01-01 the it will work for 2018-01-01 but since it has passed it wont give 2020-01-01. For he 6 Month I havent tried my formula as i was looking first to resolve the simple 2 years problem.

Comment: by posting the code.. I'm not proposing a solution.. || I was (more) meant to point you to a direction of using `date()` function plus some other function to make it work (AND to study..) .  || When developing my code... I had daringly  ASSUMED that your data is only located in cell `A1`... || To proceed, you may share us a sample file (or screenshot)..  It will clarify on the real data location and how the _"..code works but for once only..."_ really looks like.